# CMake with include and source paths - basic setup

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to set up a test project looking like my own project just to get things working first and it looks like this:

```
/MainProject/inc/main.h
/MainProject/src/main.cpp
/LibProject/inc/test.h
/LibProject/src/test.cpp
```

I've found some tutorials, but I cant find out how to set up this when I have the inc and src folder? How would the CMakeLists.txt files look? Would I have one in /, one in each of the project folders? It seems like I dont need to have one in the inc and src folders?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You need a `CMakeLists.txt` for each source subdirectory. Your structure should look something like this:

```
root
|-MainProject
| |-inc
| | '-main.h
| |-src
| | |-main.cpp
| | '-CMakeLists.txt
| '-CMakeLists.txt 
|-LibProject
| |-inc
| | '-test.h
| |-src
| | |-test.cpp
| | '-CMakeLists.txt
| '-CMakeLists.txt
'-CMakeLists.txt
```

Content of `root/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
project(MyProject)
add_subdirectory(MainProject)
add_subdirectory(LibProject)
```

Content of `LibProject/CMakeLists.txt` and `MainProject/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_subdirectory(src)
```

Content of `LibProject/src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Notice name prefix of this variable, set by CMake according
# to value given with "project()" in the root CMakeLists.txt.
include_directories(${MyProject_SOURCE_DIR}/LibProject/inc)
add_library(LibProject test.cpp)
```

Content of `MainProject/src/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(${MyProject_SOURCE_DIR}/MainProject/inc)
# I assume you want to use LibProject as a library in MainProject.
include_directories(${MyProject_SOURCE_DIR}/LibProject/inc)
link_directories(${MyProject_SOURCE_DIR}/LibProject/src)
add_executable(MainProject main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(MainProject LibProject)
```

Then configure and build with:

```
$ cd root
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ make
```

Comment: The point wasn't to copy your answer but rather to complete it. As far as I know it wouldn't work without the two missing `CMakeLists.txt`'s and the missing `link_directories()` command. I orignially intended to comment your answer, but my reputation is too low to do that. So I figured posting a 2nd answer would be the most self-containing way. Didn't mean to offend you.

Comment: It must work without link_directories as it's library built by the same project. As for path problem you are right, I'll correct it.

Comment: @user912403: So does that mean your question is solved? Then accept one of the two answers, by clicking on the check mark left to it. I would recommend Roman's one, since it's more concise. If you pick mine please verify whether the `link_directories` command in `MainProject/src/CMakeLists.txt` is really necessary, so I can edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I needed the CMakeLists.txt in the MainProject and LibProject folders aswell as in the src folders.. but subdir() didn't work.. it had to be subdirs()

Comment: Where is MyProject_SOURCE_DIR set?

Answer (score 35):

You could do it in the following way:

- CMakeLists.txt in your MainProject directory:

  ```
  project(MainProject)

  add_subdirectory(LibProject/src)
  add_subdirectory(MainProject/src)
  ```
- CMakeLists.txt in your LibProject/src directory:

  ```
  include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/LibProject/inc/)
  add_library(LibProject test.cpp)
  ```
- CMakeLists.txt in your MainProject/src directory:

  ```
  include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/MainProject/inc/)
  add_executable(MainProject main.cpp)
  target_link_libraries(MainProject LibProject)
  ```

Answer (score 29):

In my case I wanted to do it with a **single CMakeList**. And it worked for me. I add my solution in case it serves to anyone.

This is what I did in my case:

```
My structure:
Project
|CMakeLists.txt
|-src
| |*.cpp
| |*.c
|-include
| |*.hpp
| |*.h
```

My CMakeLists.txt have to main parts:

```
include_directories(
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
)
```

^ Enables .cpp files to add headers in the include folder.

```
file(GLOB all_SRCS
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.hpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c"
        )
```

^ Just add whatever is in those folders.

```
add_executable(MyTarget ${all_SRCS})
```

^ Build the target from the list of all sources

PS: if you want to see the full CMakeLists.txt go the the project link [NEGU93/ForbiddenDesert](https://github.com/NEGU93/ForbiddenDesert).

Comment: Yes, this will produce a Makefile that will properly recompile the appropriate files if the header files change. I'm not sure the previous suggestions do that (or they don't show it explicitly, at least)