# how to include inter-dependent source files from differnt sub-dirs into cmake

Tags: cmake, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Statement: I've some C code that I generally build (using Makefile) and run on Linux. But now I want to run the same code on an Android device. So here's my approach.

- Create a empty/basic activity in Android studio and add call to my C code. To start off with I'm just printing hello world and that part works. Here's the code from MainActivity.java

```
public native String helloC();
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_textview);
tv.setText(helloC());
static {    
System.loadLibrary("native-lib"); 
}
```

Here's my C code (native-lib.cpp):

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_myapp_MainActivity_helloC(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaobj) {
    return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI ! ");
}
```

I can successfully build and run this and I do see hello from JNI on the device.

- Next step is to add my code into the same directory as native-lib.cpp (cpp folder)
  [image: project_structure]

The code in app, config, common and remote have a mixture of .h, .c files and also sub-folders. The entry point into this code is remote_main() which is in remote/remote_main.c file. My plan is to call the remote_main() within my native-lib.cpp. To do that, all my source files should be compile-able. I added include_directories in cmakelist (src/main/cpp/app and so on).

Here are my 2 issues:

1. Even though I've added include_directories, I see an error with all headers saying "cannot find .h" error
2. Next issue is how do I compile all the C files within the 4 folders mentioned above and their sub-folders. I tried the method mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304190/cmake-with-include-and-source-paths-basic-setup) issue. But the problem is my code is interdependent. Files in one folder may need files from other folder. So I cannot create individual cmake file for each folder and build it independently and link them together.

This is my first time using CMake and running on Android. Any suggestion/help is appreciated.

CMakeLists.txt contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

include_directories("src/main/cpp/app" "arc/main/cpp/config" "src/main/cpp/common" "src/main/cpp/remote")
add_library( native-lib

             SHARED

             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )

find_library( log-lib log )

target_link_libraries( native-lib ${log-lib} )
```

Comment: Show your cmakelists file so we know what you tried and so we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select all `.c` files with one command and add them as "files to compile" for your `native-lib` target:

```
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE C_SOURCES "src/main/cpp/*.c")
add_library( native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             ${C_SOURCES})
target_include_directories(native-lib PRIVATE src/main/cpp/app src/main/cpp/config src/main/cpp/common src/main/cpp/remote)
```

You can add arbitrary compile definitions using `target_compile_definitions`:

```
target_compile_definitions(native-lib PRIVATE -D__FLAVOR_CLIENT)
```

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, that helped me include all my source files in the build process. I had to add "PUBLIC" to the"target_include_directories". I see an error saying use of undeclared identifier '_BUFFER_LENGTH', but this code is present. 


- - - 

#if    defined __FLAVOR_CLIENT \
    || defined __FLAVOR_SERVER \
    || defined __FLAVOR_DRIVER
....
....
# define BUFFER_LENGTH (128 * 1024)

- - -

But for some reason this code is greyed out. I'm guessing it's because I don't have __FLAVOR_* set. Is this something that can be set in cmake again?

Comment: Updated my answer. Are you sure this is supposed to be set by the compiler and not in some kind of configuration header file?

Comment: Not sure, will look into it. Thanks for the help :)