# Compile (via CMakelist) main.cpp with many source files in a single CMakelist

Tags: makefile, cmake, compilation, gnu-make, cmakelists-options

I am trying to compile a project like below.

```
myproject
|CMakeLists.txt
|-src
| |main.cpp
| |subSrc1
| | |*.cpp
| | |*.h
| |subSrc2
| | |*.cpp
| | |*.hpp
```

I want to compile project with all *.cpp and *.h.
so I made CMakeLists.txt by referring to the last comment of the url below.
[CMake with include and source paths - basic setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304190/cmake-with-include-and-source-paths-basic-setup/8304850)

```
>    cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
>     project ("myproject")
>     include_directories ("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")
>     include_directories (
>       ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
>       ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/exec/
>       ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/host/
>     )
>     
>     file(GLOB all_SRCS
>       "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp"
>       "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
>       "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/exec/*.cpp"
>       "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/exec/*.h"
>       "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/host/*.cpp"
>     )
>     
>     #add_executable (myproject "myproject/src/main.cpp")
>     add_executable (myproject ${all_SRCS})
```

but error says "NO SOURCES GIVEN TO TARGET".
I think add_executable() needs main.cpp but if I do that, there is no way to tell CMakelist the locations of other sources( .cpp and .h files).
Can I get some advise?

Comment: The message "No sources given to target" means literally that your target has **no sources**. That is, your variable `all_SRCS` is **empty**. As this variable gets its content from the `file(GLOB)`, then it means your *globbing expressions* return nothing. Please, recheck that you actually have files in the directories which you use in regular expressions.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for replying. I missed one file