# CMake cannot include headers in target_sources

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a very simply application that tries to build a main.cpp that includes a header file.
The CMake file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21.0)
project(test_app 
    VERSION 0.1.0
    LANGUAGES CXX C
)
set(CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 17)

add_executable(test_app)

target_sources(test_app PRIVATE
    main.cpp
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/myinc.h
)
```

The project structure is:

```bash
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── myinc.h
└── main.cpp
```

main.cpp includes myinc.h, but cannot find it:

***main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: myinc.h: No such file or directory***

Looking at the compile_commands.json file I see:

```json
"command": "/usr/bin/g++   -g -o CMakeFiles/scrathpad.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/supal/cppsandbox/main.cpp"
```

According to https://github.com/Bagira80/More-Modern-CMake/blob/master/OhNoMoreModernCMake.pdf (slide 10), it is recommended to do it this way.

What am I doing wrong?

P.S., my CMake version is 3.22.

Comment: `target_sources` is a list of files you compile. `target_include_directories` is for setting where compiler should look for `#include`d files (aka the `-I` option for compiler).

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703647/how-to-properly-add-include-directories-with-cmake or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304190/cmake-with-include-and-source-paths-basic-setup

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, not a duplicate. This question is not about the common use-case where I can just include the whole include dir, but the specific one where I want to selectively choose what header files I want from a given dir (there is a header name conflict if I include the whole dir). This should be possible with target_sources according to the link I provided.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, take a look at https://github.com/Bagira80/More-Modern-CMake/blob/master/OhNoMoreModernCMake.pdf  on slide 10. There it is recommended to include like that.

Comment: @SupAI Slide 10 doesn't say "You only need to add header file to `target_sources`". It says "Add header files also, it will help IDEs to understand the code". You need some combination of `-I` option and `#include` to produce a valid path to file. If you prefer, you can `#include "include/myinc.h` instead of passing `-I` option.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thanks for the clarification. As a side note, tt seems that it is now possible to add headers directly via target_sources (for CMake >= 3.23): https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_sources.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a header to the list of sources of a target doesn't affect it's availability. It's only used for some generators for influencing the source files associated with a target; e.g. for Visual Studio generators the file will be listed among the `Header Files` of your target in the solution explorer. (It also has an effect, if the header is generated during the build.)

**Note:** Even for Visual Studio generators adding the header to the sources won't result in the file being available for the `#include` directive. Providing specific files for `#include`ing only would only be possible via compiler specific options, if at all.

For making headers available via `#include` directive, you need to add a directory via [`target_include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html) such that the file in this dir using the path provided to `#include`.

```
target_include_directories(test_app PRIVATE include) # relative paths can be used here
```

Comment: This is what I'd usually do, but the include directory is from a 3rd party repo that I don't want to change. The directory contains a config_header.h that I don't want to include (I provide my own in my own repo), and some other headers that I need to include. That's why I tried to selectively include those headers. Any suggestions?
Also, why is it recommended to include via target_sources if this is not widely supported?

Comment: @SupAl It's recommended to add the headers,to get the benefit for generators where this does make a difference. It's not unsupported for other generators, it just doesn't have an effect on the project files generated.(Note: even with VS compilation fails.)As for "including headers selectively":This s rarely a good idea. Config headers like this can contain information that results in undefined behaviour,unless combined with the header used during the build of the library. You may want to create a wrapper here and limit the files including the 3rd party header to 1 (or some other small number).

Comment: So it only for certain generators. This was the answer I was looking for. I know I shouldn't do this normally (i.e., include selectively), but see my comment to Yksis.. above for why I had to do this.